# how to send data from phone to ubuntu 12.04 through bluetooth?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, phone

I have a samsung galaxy grand prime phone. I am able to send data from laptop to phone using bluetooth without any problem, but cant do the same from phone to laptop.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following after you have successfully paired your phone and Ubuntu laptop (make sure that the devices are set to *visible* ).

1. If you haven't already, then install `samba` by `sudo apt-get install samba`
2. Open dash and type `Personal File Sharing`
3. Tick `Receive files in downloads folder over bluetooth` also `enable Notify about received file`

[image]